# setlocale fails in Debug build in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, unicode

I am trying to set the string locale to UTF-8 by calling

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
```

at the beginning of my program. It is successfully set in the Release build, but fails (returns NULL and has no effect) if I build it as Debug. The settings for both Release and Debug are pretty much identical for anything that I can think of that might have an effect on this (both set to use Unicode character sets).

I can set other locales in Debug like "English" or "C", but "en_US.UTF-8" fails. Has anyone encountered this or have any idea what might be wrong?

P.S. I am linking a bunch of libraries, a couple of mine and a couple of external ones, but they're all built the same way and I'm not even sure why that would have any effect on setlocale anyway.

Comment: What macros are `define`d in the debug build?

Comment: You mean as compiler flags?  /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE"

Comment: This seems like it might be related and might be a bug in the runtime: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/330322/stdlocale-l2-en-usutf-8-broken-crashes-now.html

Comment: Have you updated VS to be up-to-date? Until fairly recently windows did not support utf-8 locale variants and I could well see the debug and release CRT libraries getting out of step. I just tried your setlocale call in a debug build and the call succeeded.

Comment: And note that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=vs-2017 still describes setlocale as failing for utf-7 and utf-8.

Comment: facing similar issue, failing setlocale.suspecting runtime library mojibake